# What should I do when there is not enough space on the Schengen application form to list all accommodation?

Tags: visas, schengen, applications

I will be travelling to Netherlands and Belgium so will be applying for a visa via the Netherlands visa center (as it'd be the country of entry for me).

The problem is that I made four booking reservations via Airbnb, two in the Netherlands and two in Belgium.

How would I go about supplying this information in the visa application?

There isn't even enough to space to put it.

Anyone had any experience with multiple bookings?

Comment: Provide the first address, but give all of the bookings as evidence anyways, so as not to leave any doubts in the visa officer's head

Comment: You mean space on the form? You can write a small note in the box and attach a separate piece of paper with the details. Or are you forced to use some online system?

Comment: @Relaxed Filling it out on paper. Do you mean I should write something like "Multiple accomodations via airbnb, see the attached itineraries"? Because I was indeed planning to attach all the itineraries.

Comment: @nainy Yes, that's what I would recommend.

Answer (score 1):

write the first address complete in visa form including address contact no 
email and fax no of Netherland bnb if your are applying from Netherland embassy.
you need to mention in your covering letter about all your stay in schengen area   with hotel name, city, and dates accordingly where you will be staying later.